# How to specify a query for COUNT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I've been searching for a bit without finding anything. I'm not 100% at home with SQL but here's what I want to do:

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Name) 
            FROM Logg WHERE Id= 1) 
* FROM Logg WHERE Id= 1
```

In other words, I want a single query, which first counts the number of rows with a distinct "Name" and then selects the top x amount of rows given that count.

How would I structure such a query?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Do you want the count number of name or the name that as the highest count number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does work - you just need to specify a column list:

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Name) FROM Logg WHERE Id= 1) * -- Need to specify columns
FROM Logg WHERE Id= 1;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0d06/1)

Comment: Yeah, hi. Sorry I forgot * but I have it in my query. No idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: With columns, your query works on Sql2008 + 2012 - I've updated the SqlFiddle. Possibly something in your filter `Where id = 1` is excluding data?

Comment: Yeah, this is obviously a local problem. I'm sorry for taking your time.

Comment: As per @Gordon's comment, can you paste some sample data and what your required outcome is? It sounds like you might want a dynamic windowing function or similar (assuming you want a more general solution than just hard filtering both the count and #rows by the same filter)

Answer (score 0):

Just separate out the query into 3 parts:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT
SELECT @cnt = COUNT (DISTINCT TestNamn) FROM SelfTestLogg WHERE ApplikationId = 1
SELECT TOP (@cnt) * FROM SelfTestLogg WHERE ApplikationId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select all names that only appear once?

If so:

```
select name
from logg
where id = 1
group by name
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Logg WHERE Id= 1
```

Comment: @user1531921 needs the TOP value as an expression, not a literal.